# SQLSpatial locally in U-SQL Catalog

Tags: c#, azure, .net-assembly, u-sql

How can I register SQLServerSpatial dll localy?  When I try I run register assembly on [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types] with SqlServerSpatial130 as addintional file I get the following issue:

E_CSC_USER_CANNOTCREATESYSTEMASSEMBLY: Cannot create assembly XXX.[Microsoft.SqlServer.Types]' because 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' is a system assembly.
Description:
System assemblies cannot be created, altered or dropped.
Resolution:
Consider creating a user assembly to wrap desired functionality.

I can register the assembly in Azure Datalake but not localy. Is there a way to fix that?

Thanks on advance

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you may have registered SQL Server on your local box or some other application that already registers Microsoft.SqlServer.Types as a system assembly.

If that is the case, you probably do not have to register it and refer to it with `REFERENCE SYSTEM ASSEMBLY` in your local run.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. When I try your suggestion of just using a system reference (i.e. REFERENCE SYSTEM ASSEMBLY [Microsoft.SqlServer.Types];), I get a compile error with Metadata file 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll' could not be found.

Any ideas on that. i tried adding the DLL as a project reference and selecting to copy it on build, but that didn't really work.